# How to place an image properly with CSS

Tags: css, image

I'm having trouble with placing an image in the correct spot in my CSS.

I have links in the left side of the page and would like an image to the top right of the nav bar.

Unsure on how that's done.

Comment: show your code or set it on jsfiddle so we can help you better

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/frjy9xus/

Comment: Take the time to read *both* the "*[ask]*" and "*[mcve]*" guidelines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

like this:

HTML

```
<nav>
   <img src="image.png" alt="image">
</nav>
```

CSS

```
nav{
       position:relative;
    }
    nav img{
       position:absolute;
       top:0;
       right:0;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can place it where you want with the bottom, top, right and left properties.
For example, to place the image 10 px from the top and 20 px from the right you can write the following:

top: 10px;

right: 20px;